# numpy: How to add a column to an existing structured array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, structured-array, recarray

I have a starting array such as:

```
[(1, [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372])
 (2, [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162])]
```

The first column is an `int` and the second is a `list` of `floats`.  I need to add a `str` column called `'USNG'`.

I then create a structured numpy array, as such:

```
dtype = numpy.dtype([('USNG', '|S100')])
x = numpy.empty(array.shape, dtype=dtype)
```

I want to append the `x` numpy array to the existing array as a new column, so I can output some information to that column for each row.

When I do the following:

```
numpy.append(array, x, axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
'TypeError: invalid type promotion'
```

I've also tried [vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to create a new dtype that contains the new field.

For example, here's `a`:

```
In [86]: a
Out[86]: 
array([(1, [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372]),
       (2, [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162])], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', '<f8', (2,))])
```

`a.dtype.descr` is `[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', '<f8', (2,))]`; i.e. a list of field types.  We'll create a new dtype by adding `('USNG', 'S100')` to the end of that list:

```
In [87]: new_dt = np.dtype(a.dtype.descr + [('USNG', 'S100')])
```

Now create a *new* structured array, `b`.  I used `zeros` here, so the string fields will start out with the value `''`.  You could also use `empty`.  The strings will then contain garbage, but that won't matter if you immediately assign values to them.

```
In [88]: b = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=new_dt)
```

Copy over the existing data from `a` to `b`:

```
In [89]: b['i'] = a['i']

In [90]: b['loc'] = a['loc']
```

Here's `b` now:

```
In [91]: b
Out[91]: 
array([(1, [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372], ''),
       (2, [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162], '')], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', '<f8', (2,)), ('USNG', 'S100')])
```

Fill in the new field with some data:

```
In [93]: b['USNG'] = ['FOO', 'BAR']

In [94]: b
Out[94]: 
array([(1, [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372], 'FOO'),
       (2, [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162], 'BAR')], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', '<f8', (2,)), ('USNG', 'S100')])
```

Comment: A performance question, if you were doing a for loop on the data update of the array, would you vectorize the function?

Comment: That depends on what type of update you are doing, and how you are going to vectorize it.  It would be more effective to start a new question instead of discussing it in these comments.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using numpy's [recfunctions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.lib.recfunctions)?

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn
```

It has some very useful functions for structured arrays.

For your case, I think it could be accomplished with:

```
a = rfn.append_fields(a, 'USNG', np.empty(a.shape[0], dtype='|S100'), dtypes='|S100')
```

Tested here and it worked.

---

### merge_arrays

As GMSL mentioned in the comments. It is possible to do that with rfn.merge_arrays like below:

```
a = np.array([(1, [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372]),
       (2, [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162])], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', '<f8', (2,))])
a2 = np.full(a.shape[0], '', dtype=[('USNG', '|S100')])
a3 = rfn.merge_arrays((a, a2), flatten=True)
```

a3 will have the value:

```
array([(1, [-112.01268502,   40.64249414], b''),
       (2, [-111.86145709,   40.49450087], b'')],
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', '<f8', (2,)), ('USNG', 'S100')])
```

Comment: the recfunction function `merge_arrays()` would be simpler in this case.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. Required a bit of tinkering to find that the flatten argument was required to give the appropriate behavior :). Editted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

with 2mil+ arrays to work with, I immediately noticed a big difference between Warren Weckesser's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25429497/15446311) and Tonsic's [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62396724/15446311) (thank you very much both)

with

```
first_array
[out]
array([(1633046400299000, 1.34707, 1.34748),
       (1633046400309000, 1.347  , 1.34748),
       (1633046400923000, 1.347  , 1.34749), ...,
       (1635551693846000, 1.36931, 1.36958),
       (1635551693954000, 1.36925, 1.36952),
       (1635551697902000, 1.3692 , 1.36947)],
      dtype=[('timestamp', '<i8'), ('bid', '<f8'), ('ask', '<f8')])
```

and

```
second_array
[out]
array([('2021-10-01T00:00:00.299000',), ('2021-10-01T00:00:00.309000',),
       ('2021-10-01T00:00:00.923000',), ...,
       ('2021-10-29T23:54:53.846000',), ('2021-10-29T23:54:53.954000',),
       ('2021-10-29T23:54:57.902000',)], dtype=[('date_time', '<M8[us]')])
```

I get

```
%timeit rfn.merge_arrays((first_array, second_array), flatten=True)
[out]
13.8 s ± 1.11 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and

```
%timeit rfn.append_fields(first_array, 'date_time', second_array, dtypes='M8[us]').data
[out]
2.12 s ± 146 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

much better (and notice `.data` at the end to avoid getting `mask` and `fill_value`)

whereas using something like

```
def building_new(first_array, other_array):
    new_array = np.zeros(
        first_array.size, 
        dtype=[('timestamp', '<i8'), ('bid', '<f8'), ('ask', '<f8'), ('date_time', '<M8[us]')])
    new_array[['timestamp', 'bid', 'ask']] = first_array[['timestamp', 'bid', 'ask']]
    new_array['date_time'] = other_array
    return new_array
```

(notice that in a structured array every row is a tuple, so size works nicely)

I get

```
%timeit building_new(first_array, second_array)
[out]
67.2 ms ± 3.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

the output of all three is the same

```
[out]
array([(1633046400299000, 1.34707, 1.34748, '2021-10-01T00:00:00.299000'),
       (1633046400309000, 1.347  , 1.34748, '2021-10-01T00:00:00.309000'),
       (1633046400923000, 1.347  , 1.34749, '2021-10-01T00:00:00.923000'),
       ...,
       (1635551693846000, 1.36931, 1.36958, '2021-10-29T23:54:53.846000'),
       (1635551693954000, 1.36925, 1.36952, '2021-10-29T23:54:53.954000'),
       (1635551697902000, 1.3692 , 1.36947, '2021-10-29T23:54:57.902000')],
      dtype=[('timestamp', '<i8'), ('bid', '<f8'), ('ask', '<f8'), ('date_time', '<M8[us]')])
```

a final thought:

creating the new array instead of the recfunctions, the second array doesn't even need to be a structured one

```
third_array
[out]
array(['2021-10-01T00:00:00.299000', '2021-10-01T00:00:00.309000',
       '2021-10-01T00:00:00.923000', ..., '2021-10-29T23:54:53.846000',
       '2021-10-29T23:54:53.954000', '2021-10-29T23:54:57.902000'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')

%timeit building_new(first_array, third_array)
[out]
67 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wish this answer was voted more highly. It has the most useful with the timings. What affect would number of fields have on these various methods? More fields meaning wider struct arrays.

Answer (score 2):

- If [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is an option, it makes adding a column to a `recarray`, much easier.

  - Additionally, the data will be in a form that's easily analyzed
  - [numpy](https://numpy.org/) is a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) dependency, and makes many operations easier.
  - Also see [How to add a column to numpy recarry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675042) as another example.

1. Read the current `recarray` with [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).
2. Add the new column of data to the dataframe
3. Export the dataframe to a `recarray` with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# current recarray
data = np.rec.array([(1, list([-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372])), (2, list([-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162]))], dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', 'O')])

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
   i                                       loc
0  1  [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372]
1  2   [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162]

# add new column
df['USNG'] = ['Note 1', 'Note 2']

# display(df)
   i                                       loc    USNG
0  1  [-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372]  Note 1
1  2   [-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162]  Note 2

# write the dataframe to recarray
data = df.to_records(index=False)

print(data)
[out]:
rec.array([(1, list([-112.01268501699997, 40.64249414272372]), 'Note 1'),
           (2, list([-111.86145708699996, 40.4945008710162]), 'Note 2')],
          dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('loc', 'O'), ('USNG', 'O')])
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is precisely: "Any suggestions on why this is happening?"

Fundamentally, this is a [bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2676)--- it's been an open ticket at numpy since 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that implements Warren's solution:

```
def happend(x, col_data,col_name:str):
    if not x.dtype.fields:  return None                                     # Not a structured array
    y = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=x.dtype.descr+[(col_name,col_data.dtype)])  # 0) create new structured array
    for name in x.dtype.fields.keys():  y[name] = x[name]                   # 1) copy old array
    y[col_name] = col_data                                                  # 2) copy new column
    return y

y = happend(x, np.arange(x.shape[0]),'idx')  # assuming `x` is a structured array
```

Comment: Hi Diego. I can't recall if we have had this conversation before, apologies. It is a strong editing guideline here that anything not germane to a post can be removed. We have a loose network of curators and editors who like to improve posts towards technical writing, so the Q&A material here sort-of resembles documentation or wiki material.

Comment: Thus political/religious/theistic material is often removed on sight - 'tis house style (un)fortunately! There is wide leeway for you to add what you like in your profile though.

Answer (score 0):

Tonsic mentioned the recfunctions by `import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn`. In this case, a simpler recfunction function that would work for you is `rfn.merge_arrays()` ([docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays)).